# Relative Layout getParams and setMargin Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to programmatically give margin. API 23 does not work on my phone.
API 28 works on my phone.  How can I handle this?

```
paramsFlow1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mRelativeFlow1.getLayoutParams();
paramsFlow1.setMarginStart(Utils.convertDpToPixel(70,Activity.this));
```